# Accessing data from one class to another in android

Tags: java, android

Hi In this Application I have created a form with the following code. After clicking save Button, the data got saved into database. Now if I search some `mobile_no` means I am accessing all the data by using one class.
By using that I am accessing that field for which I have written the following code.
Now in my Logcat, it is showing unfortunately error. Can any one please help me with where I did mistake?

**PatientRegistration.java**

```
public class PatientRegistration extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    EditText regno1,fname1,mname1,lname1,dob1,age1,f_hname1,adress1,tel_o1,pin_zip1,tel_r,email1,mobile1,id_prof1,b_group1,name_kin1,relation1;
    String data="";
    TextView tv1;

    Button back,home,choosefile;
    Spinner initial,pmaincat,pcatory,religion,caste;
    RadioGroup sex,payment;
    RadioButton rb;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    String[] initial_name,initial_id,patient_main_type_name,patient_type_name,religion_name,caste_name,reg_no,patient_main_type_id,patient_type_id,religion_id,caste_id;
    private EditText fromDateEtxt;
    private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
    private String selectedImagePath;
    private Map<String, String> patmainMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Map<String, String> patcatMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Map<String, String> regMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Map<String, String> casteMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Map<String, String> initialMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.pat_registration);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);


        payment = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.sex);
        int selectedId = payment.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

        back=(Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        home=(Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
        fname1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);        
        lname1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        regno1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.rgno);
        regno1.setEnabled(false);
        mname1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mname);

        age1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        f_hname1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.f_hname);
        adress1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.adress);        
        tel_o1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.telo);
        pin_zip1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pzipcode);
        tel_r=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tel_r);
        email1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mobile1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);        
        id_prof1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.idprof);
        b_group1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.bgroup);
        name_kin1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_kin);
        relation1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.relationship);


        initial=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.intial);
        pmaincat=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.pmaincat);
        pcatory=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.pcatgory);
        religion=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.religion);
        caste=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.caste);

        sex=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.sex);
        payment=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.paymentmode);

        tv1.setText("PATIENT REGISTRATION");
       final Button photo1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.photo);    
        Button Send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Send); 

        Send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {             
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                 Global.first_name = fname1.getText().toString();
                 String middle_name = mname1.getText().toString(); 
                 String last_name = lname1.getText().toString(); 
                 String reg_no = regno1.getText().toString();
                 String dob = fromDateEtxt.getText().toString();
                 String age = age1.getText().toString();
                 String address = adress1.getText().toString(); 
                 String phone_office = tel_o1.getText().toString(); 
                 String fh = f_hname1.getText().toString(); 
                 String pin = pin_zip1.getText().toString();
                 String phone_resi = tel_r.getText().toString();
                 String email = email1.getText().toString(); 
                 String mobile_no = mobile1.getText().toString(); 
                 String id_proof = id_prof1.getText().toString();
                 String blood_group = b_group1.getText().toString();
                 String name_of_kin = name_kin1.getText().toString(); 
                 String relation = relation1.getText().toString(); 

                 String gender=  ((RadioButton)findViewById(sex.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();  
              String pmode=  ((RadioButton)findViewById(payment.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();

                 String photo = photo1.getUrls().toString(); 

                 String patient_main_type_name = patmainMap.get(String
                        .valueOf(pmaincat.getSelectedItem()));
                 String pc = patcatMap.get(String
                        .valueOf(pcatory.getSelectedItem()));


                 String religion_id = regMap.get(String
                        .valueOf(religion.getSelectedItem()));


                 String caste_id=casteMap.get(String
                            .valueOf(caste.getSelectedItem()));
                 String initial_id=initialMap.get(String
                            .valueOf(initial.getSelectedItem()));



                 Toast.makeText(
                        PatientRegistration.this,
                        "Result : " + "\nclassId : " + initial_id
                        ,

                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


               /* if(first_name.equals(""))
                {           
                    fname1.setError( "Please Enter First Name" );
                }
                else if(last_name.equals(""))
                {           
                    lname1.setError( "Please Enter Last Name" );
                }   
                if(reg_no.equals(""))
                {           
                    fname1.setError( "Please Select Religon" );
                }
                else if(last_name.equals(""))
                {           
                    lname1.setError( "Please Enter Last Name" );
                }   
                else if(mobile.equals(""))
                {           
                    mobile1.setError( "Please Enter Mobile No." );

                }
                else if(!isValidMobile(mobile)){


                }

                else if(email.equals(""))
                {           
                    email1.setError( "Please Enter EmailId" );
                }
                else if(!isValidMail(email)){


                }


                else
                {
*/
                    try{

                        String queryString ="reg_no="+ reg_no
                                 +"&pmc="+patient_main_type_name+"&pc="+pc+ "&initial_id="+initial_id+"&first_name="+Global.first_name+"&middle_name="+middle_name+"&last_name="+last_name
                                 +"&fh="+fh+"&religion_id="+religion_id+"&dob="+dob+"&caste_id="+caste_id+"&address="+address+"&pin="+pin
                                 +"&email="+email+"&id_proof="+id_proof+"&phone_office="+phone_office+"&phone_resi="+phone_resi+"&mobile_no="+mobile_no+"&name_of_kin="+name_of_kin
                                 +"&relation="+relation+"&blood_group="+blood_group+"&photo="+photo+"&pmode="+pmode;
                    data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("pat_registration",queryString);
                    /*fname1.setText("");
                    lname1.setText("");
                     mobile1.setText("");
                     altmob1.setText("");
                     email1.setText("");
                     comment1.setText("");*/
                    Toast.makeText(
                            PatientRegistration.this,
                            "Message:Records Saved Sucessfully",

                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                     catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }
        });
        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);

        findViewsById();

        setDateTimeField();
        String result = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("initialName","");
        System.out.print(result);

        try
        {
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result);



            initial_name = new String[JA.length()];
            initial_id = new String[JA.length()];




            for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
            {
              initial_name[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("initial_name");
              initial_id[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("initial_id");
              initialMap.put(initial_name[i],initial_id[i]);
            }
             spinner_fn();            
        }     
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String pat_main_type_id = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("pat_main_type_name","");
        System.out.print(pat_main_type_id);

        try
        {
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(pat_main_type_id);
            JSONObject json = null;
            patient_main_type_id = new String[JA.length()];
            patient_main_type_name = new String[JA.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
            {
                json = JA.getJSONObject(i);
                patient_main_type_id[i] = json.getString("patient_main_type_id");
                patient_main_type_name[i] = json.getString("patient_main_type_name");
              patmainMap.put(patient_main_type_name[i],patient_main_type_id[i]);
            }

             spinner_fn();

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String RegNo = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("reg","");
        System.out.print(RegNo);

        try
        {
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(RegNo);




            reg_no = new String[JA.length()];
        String value = "PAT";
            for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
                        {

                            reg_no[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("reg_no");
                            value+=reg_no[i];


                        }

            regno1.setText(value);



        }
      catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String pat_catgory = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("pat_catgory","");
        System.out.print(pat_catgory);

        try
        {
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(pat_catgory);


            patient_type_id = new String[JA.length()];
            patient_type_name = new String[JA.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)

            {
                patient_type_id[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("patient_type_id");
                patient_type_name[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("patient_type_name");
                patcatMap.put(patient_type_name[i], patient_type_id[i]);

            }

             spinner_fn();


        }
         catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String religion = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("religion","");
        System.out.print(religion);

        try
        {
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(religion);



            religion_id= new String[JA.length()];
            religion_name= new String[JA.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
            {
                religion_id[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("religion_id");
                religion_name[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("religion_name");
                regMap.put(religion_name[i], religion_id[i]);


            }

             spinner_fn();


        }


        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String caste = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("caste","");
        System.out.print(caste);

        try
        {
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(caste);



            caste_id= new String[JA.length()];
            caste_name= new String[JA.length()];


            for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
            {

                caste_id[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("caste_id");
                caste_name[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("caste_name");
               casteMap.put(caste_name[i],caste_id[i]);
            }

             spinner_fn();


        }


        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                onBackPressed();

            }
        });
 home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    }
    private void spinner_fn() {

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                initial_name);
        dataAdapter
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        initial.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        initial.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {

                Log.e("Position new", initial_name[position]);



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                patient_main_type_name);
        dataAdapter1
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        pmaincat.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);

        pmaincat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {

                Log.e("Position new", patient_main_type_name[position]);



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                patient_type_name);
        dataAdapter2
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        pcatory.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);

        pcatory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {

                Log.e("Position new", patient_main_type_name[position]);



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                religion_name);
        dataAdapter3
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        religion.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);

        religion.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {

                Log.e("Position new", patient_main_type_name[position]);



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                caste_name);
        dataAdapter4
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        caste.setAdapter(dataAdapter4);

        caste.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {

                Log.e("Position new", patient_main_type_name[position]);



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });

    }
    private void findViewsById() {
        fromDateEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dob);
        fromDateEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        fromDateEtxt.requestFocus();

    }

    private void setDateTimeField() {
        fromDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate
                        .getTime()));
            }

        }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){


        super.onBackPressed();      
    }

    private boolean isValidMail(String email) 
    {
        boolean check;
        Pattern p;
        Matcher m;

        String EMAIL_STRING = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        p = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_STRING);

        m = p.matcher(email);
        check = m.matches();

        if(!check)
        {
            email1.setError("Not Valid Email");
        }
        return check;
    }
    private boolean isValidMobile(String mobile) 
    {
        boolean check;
        if(mobile.length() < 6 || mobile.length() > 13)
        {
            check = false;
            mobile1.setError("Not Valid Number");
        }
        else
        {
            check = true;
        }
        return check;
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == fromDateEtxt) {
            fromDatePickerDialog.show();
        }

    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                //img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

**OPD_Registration.java**

```
public class OPD_Registration extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    EditText age,fname1,mname1,lname1,dob1,age1adress1,tel_o1,pin_zip1,tel_r,email1,mobile1,b_group1,sex,dob,address,religion,caste,entry_date;
    String data="";
    TextView tv1;

    Button back,home;
    Spinner department,ref_doctor,consl_doctor;


    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    String[] department_name,department_id,patient_main_type_name,patient_type_name,religion_name,caste_name;
    private EditText fromDateEtxt;
    private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
    private String selectedImagePath;
    private Map<String, String> departMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Map<String, String> ref_doctMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Map<String, String> cons_doctMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.opd_registration);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);




        back=(Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        home=(Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
        fname1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);        
        lname1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        age=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        sex=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.sex);
        dob=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.dob);

        mname1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mname);

        address=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.adress);     
        tel_o1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.telo);
        pin_zip1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pzipcode);
        tel_r=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tel_r);
        email1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mobile1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);        
        tel_o1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.telo);
        b_group1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.bgroup);
        tel_r=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tel_r);
        religion=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.religion);
        caste=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.caste);
        entry_date=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etdate);

        department=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.intial);
        ref_doctor=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.pmaincat);
        consl_doctor=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.pcatgory);




        tv1.setText("OPD REGISTRATION");


       fname1.setText(Global.first_name);
       mname1.setText(Global.middle_name);
        lname1.setText(Global.last_name);

        fromDateEtxt.setText(Global.dob);

        tel_o1.setText(Global.phone_office);

        pin_zip1.setText(Global.pin);
        tel_r.setText(Global.phone_resi);
        email1.setText(Global.email); 
        mobile1.setText(Global.mobile_no); 

        b_group1.setText(Global.blood_group);

        String queryString ="reg_no="+Global.reg_no
               +"&mobile_no="+Global.mobile_no;
   data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("Opd_Reg",queryString);
```

**Logcat**

```
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vcarehospital/com.example.vcarehospital.OPD_Registration}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at com.example.vcarehospital.OPD_Registration.onCreate(OPD_Registration.java:135)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     ... 11 more


    11-04 08:38:17.613: E/AndroidRuntime(4002): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vcarehospital/com.example.vcarehospital.OPD_Registration}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Add complete stacktrace please.

Comment: wich line is line 135 in `OPD_Registration.java`

Comment: fromDateEtxt.setText(Global.dob);

Comment: can you please tell me

Answer (score 0):

NPE here:

> ```
> fromDateEtxt.setText(Global.dob);
> ```

You haven't initialized `fromDateEtxt` with `findViewById()` like you're initializing some other view references.

Generally, errors like these are easy to figure out with the stacktrace and possibly a debugger. Learning to use both is essential for an Android developer.